# Determine most similar phrase with word2vec

Tags: python, doc2vec

I create a Python script for training and inferring test document vectors using  doc2vec.

My problem is when I try to determine the most similar phrase for example ("the world") it shows me only on the list of most similar words. It didn't shows the list of most similar phrase.

Am I missing something in my code?

```
#python example to infer document vectors from trained doc2vec model
import gensim.models as g
import codecs

#parameters
model="toy_data/model.bin"
test_docs="toy_data/test_docs.txt"
output_file="toy_data/test_vectors.txt"

#inference hyper-parameters
start_alpha=0.01
infer_epoch=1000

#load model
m = g.Doc2Vec.load(model)
test_docs = [ x.strip().split() for x in codecs.open(test_docs, "r", "utf-8").readlines() ]

#infer test vectors
output = open(output_file, "w")
for d in test_docs:
    output.write( " ".join([str(x) for x in m.infer_vector(d, alpha=start_alpha, steps=infer_epoch)]) + "\n" )
output.flush()
output.close()


m.most_similar('the word'.split())
```

I get this list :

```
[('refutations', 0.9990279078483582),
 ('volume', 0.9989271759986877),
 ('italic', 0.9988381266593933),
 ('syllogisms', 0.998751699924469),
 ('power', 0.9987285137176514),
 ('alibamu', 0.9985184669494629),
 ("''", 0.99847412109375),
 ('roman', 0.9984466433525085),
 ('soil', 0.9984269738197327),
 ('plants', 0.9984176754951477)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Doc2Vec` model collects its doc-vectors for later lookup or search in a property `.docvecs`. To get doc-vector results, you would perform a `most_similar()` on that property. If your `Doc2Vec` instance is held in a variable `d2v_model`, and `doc_id` holds one of the known doc-tags from training, that might be:

```
d2v_model.docvecs.most_similar(doc_id)
```

If you were inferring a vector for a new document, and looking up training docs similar to that inferred vector, your code might be like:

```
new_dv = d2v_model.infer_vector('some new document'.split())
d2v_model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[new_dv])
```

(The `Doc2Vec` model class is derived from the very-similar `Word2Vec` class, and thus inherits a `most_similar()` which by default consults just the internal word-vectors. Those word-vectors might be useful, in some `Doc2Vec` modes, or random – but it's best to use either `d2v_model.wv.most_similar()` or `d2v_model.docvecs.most_similar()` to be clear.)

Basic `Doc2Vec` examples, like the notebook installed with `gensim` in the `docs/notebooks` directory [`doc2vec-lee.ipynb`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb), contain useful examples.